# How to exclude directories outside project root in clion?

Tags: clion

I'm trying to mark some system folders under /usr as exclude, but when I chose the mark as I only get the two other options, mark as library or project source/header. Then I read [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/12/mark-dir-as/) that you can only exclude directories under your project root. Now is there a workaround to prevent clion to index files outside of my project root? Or to somehow exclude them? Seems like a strange feature to allow people to manually exclude folders, but to limit it to the project scope.